# How to add previous month value with current month revenue and show in current month in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data on Customer wise revenue by month

[image]

Output requires:-

[image]

where January month data is the new value and after that next month is the calculation of current month value plus just previous month value
i.e. Feb 2020 value = Current Feb month value + Previous month Jan value

How to do the above calculation in Power BI?

Comment: Do you have a date table @Pradeep Kumar

Comment: @BOUBRITNacim No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following measure:

```
YTD=
   VAR date = SELECTEDVALUE(table[date])
   RETURN CALCULATE( SUM(table[value], 
                     ALL(table[date]), 
                     table[date] <= date)
```

Comment: thanks, not exact the above measure works but yes its gives idea and the formula get works